# IPython and virtualenv: ignoring site-packages

Tags: virtualenv, ipython

Does anyone know how to get IPython to ignore site-packages in the context of a virtualenv that was created with the --no-site-packages flag?

Comment: On Linux & Mac, if the first line of your `ipython` script (`which ipython` should find it) is `#!/usr/bin/env python`, it should obey the virtualenv when it starts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ipython is not virtualenv aware.  There are several examples on the web of how to make ipython understand virtualenvs: for instance [here](http://blog.ufsoft.org/2009/1/29/ipython-and-virtualenv) and [here](http://www.swegler.com/becky/blog/2011/08/28/python-django-mysql-on-windows-7-part-3-ipython-virtual-environments/).  That said, you may need to manipulate the environment a little more than these examples to remove the global site-packages dir(s) from the ipython's path.

Comment: virtualenv is supported by ipython from version 0.13 up (http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.13/whatsnew/version0.13.html), but site-packages are still included.