# Can't install downloaded package in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've downloaded a repository [Django class fixtures](https://github.com/jklaiho/django-class-fixtures) and I wanted to install it with python setup.py install in my virtualenv:

```
(test)/tmp/django-class-fixtures $ which python
/home/kuba/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python
(test)/tmp/django-class-fixtures $ python setup.py install
...
Extracting django_class_fixtures-0.8-py2.7.egg to /home/kuba/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Adding django-class-fixtures 0.8 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/kuba/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_class_fixtures-0.8-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for django-class-fixtures==0.8
Finished processing dependencies for django-class-fixtures==0.8
(test)/tmp/django-class-fixtures $
```

But nothig except egg is installed:

```
(test)/tmp/django-class-fixtures $ cdvirtualenv
(test)/home/kuba/.virtualenvs/test $ cd lib/python2.7/site-packages
(test)/home/kuba/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages $ ls
django                               PIL
Django-1.4-py2.7.egg-info            PIL.pth
django_class_fixtures-0.8-py2.7.egg  pip-1.1-py2.7.egg
easy-install.pth                     setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
IPython                              setuptools.pth
ipython-0.12-py2.7.egg-info
(test)/home/kuba/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages $
```

Have you any ideas what's wrong?

Edit:
I want to import class_fixtures from shell for example:

```
(test)/home/kuba/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages $ ipython
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.11 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import class_fixtures
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/kuba/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/<ipython-input-1-6a049da89661> in <module>()
----> 1 import class_fixtures

ImportError: No module named class_fixtures

In [2]:
```

Comment: what do you expect more?

Comment: I expect that I can import class_fixtures in shell- I've updated question

Comment: The module is called `django_class_fixtures`

Comment: Nope- ImportError: No module named django_class_fixtures. Problem is that in site-packages is no module called django_class_fixtures or class_fixtures

Comment: The egg file and an entry in a .pth file is all that is needed if the package is zip safe. Python will transparently import directly from the egg. What does sys.path say?

Comment: Whoa- now I see that ipython has sys.path different from 'normal' python- that's wired. But in general- you are right, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't that the package isn't being installed, it's that IPython ignores the packages in your virtualenv, as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7391654/679254). I think you'll find that firing up an interactive shell with just `python` will allow you to import everything fine.

To get IPython to recognize site packages, put something like this in a file named `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/00-virtualenv.py` or something similar:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import site
from os import environ
from os.path import join
from sys import version_info

if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in environ:
    virtual_env = join(
        environ.get('VIRTUAL_ENV'),
        'lib',
        'python%d.%d' % version_info[:2],
        'site-packages'
    )
    site.addsitedir(virtual_env)
    print('VIRTUAL_ENV ->', virtual_env)
    del virtual_env
    del site, environ, join, version_info
```