# How to add new default packages to virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, ipython

When I create a virtualenv, it installs setuptools and pip. Is it possible to add new packages to this list?

Example use cases:

- Following [this solution](http://blog.ufsoft.org/2009/1/29/ipython-and-virtualenv) to use ipython in virtualenv (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335992/ipython-and-virtualenv-ignoring-site-packages)) requires installing ipython in every virtualenv (unless I allow system-site-packages).
- Or if I'm doing a only flask/pygame/framework development, I'd want it in every virtualenv.

Comment: I would tell you to try docker images instead of virtual envs, there are official docker images that contain all required packages you need, and you can pull it and run it and do your development stuff easily, and like envs, everything is isolated.

Comment: @alim91: I use virtualenv to help keep track of my package's dependencies (avoid accidental dependencies), so I'm looking for the opposite of "all required packages". That's why I don't include system-site-packages.

Comment: you can build your own image in docker, you 're not restricted to use their docker image with its dependencies, what I was saying that you can start from their official image because it is verified.

Answer (score 3):

I took a different approach from what is chosen as the correct answer.

I chose I directory, like `~/.virtualenv/deps` and installed packages in there by doing

```
pip install -U --target ~/.virtualenv/deps ...
```

Next in `~/.virtualenv/postmkvirtualenv` I put the following:

```
# find directory
SITEDIR=$(virtualenvwrapper_get_site_packages_dir)
PYVER=$(virtualenvwrapper_get_python_version)

# create new .pth file with our path depending of python version
if [[ $PYVER == 3* ]];
then
    echo "$HOME/.virtualenvs/deps3/" > "$SITEDIR/extra.pth";
else
    echo "$HOME/.virtualenvs/deps/" > "$SITEDIR/extra.pth";
fi
```

[Post that basically says the same thing](http://www.pygopar.com/how-to-add-default-packages-to-a-virtualenv).

Answer (score 3):

You can write a python script, say `personalize_venv.py` that extends the `EnvBuilder` class and override its `post_setup()` method for installing any default packages that you need.

You can get the basic example from https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#an-example-of-extending-envbuilder.

This doesn't need a hook. Directly run the script with command line argument `dirs` pointing  to your venv directory/directories. The hook is the `post_setup()` method itself of `EnvBuilder` class.

Comment: How do you hook this new EnvBuilder into creating a virtual env? Do you have to run it manually? Do you run it instead of `virtualenv`?

Comment: Please refer the link in the answer.

Comment: I did, and I still don't understand. "Creators of third-party virtual environment tools will be free to use the provided EnvBuilder class as a base class." But I'm not making a 3rd party tool. I just want to customize it.