# What is the purpose of the "include" folder after creating a virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-venv

I'm familiarizing myself with using venv (python3) in Windows. When I create a venv *test* and I activate the environment, I notice that there are three directories:

```
myproject
└── test
    ├── include
    ├── lib
        ├── site-packages
    ├── scripts
    └── pyvenv.cfg
```

I can see that lib contains all the libraries that I eventually download from pip/my favourite package manager. Scripts contains the logic for activating/deactivating said environments and python binaries. I am unsure about the purpose of the "Include" folder. Are there any consequences to deleting the folder?

In addition, I am keeping a collection of packages located somewhere on a network share that I'd like to include with the venv by default. This directory contains all the ones that have been vetted for safe use on the network at work. Is it possible to roll it into the creation of the venv or do that after the venv is created (ie. Copying the contents of that repository to test/lib/site-packages, then run pip install on each of them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be consequences of deleting it `include`. Actually, there *most likely* will be big consequences for deleting that folder. The `include` folder stores the c and python stuff (like writing modules in c and importing them in python). If you delete it you may break all your modules.

Comment: I probably won't ever write C so I can ignore and keep this folder. Are you able to answer my second question?

Comment: @moosearch -- No, no! Python's modules depend on that!

Comment: My comment was worded funny. Yeah, I'll leave the folder alone then

Comment: @moosearch -- as for your second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025100/how-to-add-new-default-packages-to-virtualenv

Comment: @moosearch -- The first link in that link is broken. Use this one: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/16.7.9/reference.html?highlight=creating-your-own-bootstrap-scripts#creating-your-own-bootstrap-scripts